# How to code a CLI menu interface similar to octave documentation menu interface in windows operating system in C programming language

Tags: c, windows, menu, command-line-interface, octave

After opening Octave in CLI mode and searching for help, I landed in the beautifully managed Documentation Menu Context in Windows CLI even a highlighted arrow key movement and status bar at bottom.

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

In Linux, ncurses is generally used to create beautiful CLI Application Interfaces. I just want to know how they managed to do this Menu Context in Windows CLI (since Windows doesn't support ncurses)?

It would be better if anyone can supply an example with code.

[Note: Don't suggest novice ways for creating menu contexts]

Comment: Octave is open source. Did you look at the sources?

Comment: @CrisLuengo i am trying, can you help me find it quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Octave is using ginfo from the texinfo package (https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/) to display the help.

It (texinfo) attempts to compile using ncurses, but can also use termcap for console functions instead.

In octave in windows, it is using termcap (https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_mono/termcap.html)

which provides information on the commands that can be sent to the terminal to move the cursor, scroll, set windows, change text appearance and more.

Answer (score 1):

When stdout is not redirected you can use the low-level [Windows console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) to draw text in a foreground/background color of your choosing at a specific position.

Use `SetConsoleCursorInfo`+`SetConsoleCursorPosition` to control the cursor, `ReadConsoleInput` to read input events and `WriteConsoleOutput` or `FillConsoleOutput*` to write to the console window.